# attempting to npm start react app results in blank page

Tags: reactjs

I created my app according to the instructions here:

https://reactjs.org/tutorial/tutorial.html#setup-for-the-tutorial

https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app

This is the code in my index.js file:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom/client';
import './index.css';
import Logo from './assets/blacklogo.png'

const Header = () => {
    return (
        <div className="header">
            <div className='headerLogo'>
                <img src={Logo} alt='Cool Image'></img>
                <h1>'Hello world'</h1>
            </div>
        </div>
    );
}

export default Header;
```

I have attempted reloading the page and ddouble checking to see if I have loops anywhere

Comment: Where you are calling this component?

Comment: export default Header;

Comment: This is export I'm asking where you are calling the component.

Answer (score 0):

I have discovered the issue, I was writing in index.js as opposed to App.js